# Excel: Export one ribbon tab with all it's macros

Tags: excel, export, ribbon

I've done my own Excel ribbon tab with my own macros placed in my personal.xlsb. I want to share this ribbon tab with my colleagues but I haven't figured out how to export it in a way that all macros gets included and my colleagues own customized ribbons aren't replaced. How do I do this? add-in? Some kind of executable? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Given that the UI says 'Export all customizations', Microsoft implies that it's only possible to export/import the sum of the ribbons.

Their warning also suggests this is (currently) the way to export/import; they *might* add single ribbon import/export feature(s) in future versions of Office.

> When you import a ribbon customization file, you lose all prior ribbon
>   and Quick Access Toolbar customizations. If you think that you might
>   want to revert to the customization that you currently have, you
>   should export them before importing any new customizations.

Source: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/export-or-import-a-customized-ribbon-HA101850649.aspx